# HTML table cells with input type as text not appearing when converting table to excel sheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a utility in my project where I have a HTML table whose few of the cells have input box to which I have provided a default value using `value` attribute of `input` tag. Making myself more clear with below code:

```
<table id="certain_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>SL. no.</td>
<td>Student Name</td>
<td>Marks</td>
<td>School Name</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" value="Vipul Tyagi" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="80" /></td>
<td><p>XYZ Public School</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using below Javascript code to convert above table to Excel:

```
function fnExcelReport()
  {
      var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr style='font-size: 11px !important; font-family: Calibri;'>";
      var textRange; var j=0;
      tab = document.getElementById('certain_table'); // id of table
  
      for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
      {     
          tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
          //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
      }
  
      tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
      tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
      tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");
      tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
  
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
      var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
      link.download = "StudentRecord_Vipul.xls";
      link.click();

  }
```

Where `fnExcelReport` is invoked on click of a button.
The problem is that only those cells are appearing in excel report where the table cell is plain text. Those cells which have input box are not appearing in the excel report even though I have given them default value.

Do you guys know how can I make these fields appear in the report?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you're using the '.innerHTML' property to get the value of the cells, instead of the 'value' property of the input fields(which you've placed in the cells).

You could rewrite this line to something like:

tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].cells[i].firstChild.value+"

Where i is the cell number in that row and you're iterating through your row.